# why access memory error when malloc the size so large?

Tags: c++, windows, memory-leaks, malloc, large-data

As this you can see,  when I run it, I got memory access error .but if
I change the malloc_size to 100,it can work. How to fix it without changing malloc_size.

```
int malloc_size = 900000;
float* ptr = (float *)malloc(malloc_size);


for (int i = 0; i< malloc_size; i ++) {

    ptr[i] = 0;
}
```

Comment: please tag the language you are using only

Comment: `(float *)malloc(malloc_size);` -- How many `float`'s are being created here?  If you say "there are malloc_size floats being created", you're wrong.

Comment: *but if I change the malloc_size to 100,it can work* -- No it does not "work".  You are accessing items out-of-bounds, which means you are invoking undefined behavior.

Comment: You can use calloc to allocate all zeroed out memory `float* ptr = (float*)calloc(malloc_size, sizeof(float));`.

Comment: Changing to `float *ptr = new float[malloc_size];` will remove the problem. This assumes that `malloc_size` is intended to be the number of **elements** in the array, which is what the `for` loop implies, rather than the number of **bytes**.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`malloc` accepts the amount of bytes to allocate as a parameter.
Let's say your `malloc_size` was 100 for the sake of simplicity.

The for loop iterating while `i < malloc_size` can exceed that limit because inside, you're accessing `ptr[i] = 0;`. `ptr` is a pointer to a `float`, which is most likely four bytes large. This means that `ptr[i]` accesses the byte at offset `i * sizeof(float)`, or `i * 4`. When `i` reaches 25, you're accessing the byte at offset `25 * 4 = 100`, which is one past the end.

Accessing an array out of bounds is *undefined behavior*, and in your case, it leads to a program crash.

#### C++ Advice

Since this question is tagged [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b), I also recommend not to use `malloc` at all.
A much better alternative is `new`:

```cpp
float* ptr = new float[100] {}; // array of size 100
                                // all elements are initialized to zero
// ...
delete[] ptr;
```

You still have to manage memory manually with `new` and `delete`, so it would be much easier to use [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead:

```cpp
#include <vector>
// ...

std::vector<float> vec(100); // vector of size 100
                             // all elements are initialized to zero
// no need to free/delete
```